# Есть видео уроки по созданию расширения для devtools?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

Есть видео уроки по созданию расширения для devtools?

Comment: Уроков не находил, но могу поделиться своим проектом - я работал над дополнительной панелью devtools. Расширение позволяет парсить JSON, хранимый в localStorage / sessionStorage. [Репозиторий тут.](https://github.com/Deliaz/local-storage-explorer)